# How do I create a number Value to an radioButton in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I'm having issue trying to assign different number values to a number a Radiobuttons, to then calculate together as a total sum into a textbox, but not sure where to start, im new to C# and not understanding to well, if anyone can provide a simple example I would be grateful

So far I've come up with something like this, just to try to assing the number value but cant get it to work, and not even sure how to add them together after?
Do I need to use: int?

```
int Basic, Reg, Pre

        {
            If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Basic = 10;


            If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Reg = 15;


            If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Pre = 20;
```

Comment: Do you only have a single radio button?

Comment: This is not C#. This is not VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Looks mostly like Visual Basic. Try to find a beginner's tutorial on C# on the internet.

In this case the variables may not be assigned a value in the `if` statements. Unlike vb, you need to explicitly assign the default values to the variables before we try to add them at the end.

In C# `If` is `if` (most statements are lowercase) and the condition (the part that evaluates to true of false) is in parentheses.

In C# the assignment operator `=` is different from the comparison operator `==` which is used in many `if` statements. You could write

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
```

but, since `.Checked` evaluates to `true` or `false` you can skip the `== true`.

```
if (radioButton2.Checked)
```

The code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Basic = 0;
        int Reg = 0;
        int Pre = 0;


        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            Basic = 10;

        if (radioButton2.Checked)
            Reg = 15;

        if (radioButton3.Checked)
            Pre = 20;

        txtTotal.Text = (Basic + Reg + Pre).ToString();
    }
```

One last thing. `ToString` requires the method invoker `()`. vb is lazy about this. vb also allows you to skip it for constructors but you will need it in C#.

**EDIT**
Users can enter anything in a text box. To keep your code from blowing up it is best to use TryParse to verify a valid number. The first parameter is the string you want to convert. The second is a variable of the appropriate type to hold the converted value. The function returns True of False depending on the success of the conversion. The exclamation mark is Not in C#. If the conversion fails we inform the user and exit the method with return. If successful we continue to the multiplication with the converted values.

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Double.TryParse(textbox5.Text,out double txt1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in textbox 5");
            return;
        }
         if (!Double.TryParse(textbox6.Text,out double txt2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in textbox 6");
            return;
        }
        double sum = txt1 * txt2; 
        textbox7.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, this has helped a lot, if I am wanting to add a few radiobutton values together  that are placed in a textbox from the option thats selected would something like this work?

 textBox5.Text = ( Basic, reg, pre, * textbox4.text )
or
double txt1 =convert.todouble(textbox5.text);
double txt2 =convert.todouble(textbox6.text);

double sum = txt1 * txt2;
textbox7.text = sum.ToString();

Comment: You can't do arithmetic with a string. The Text property of a textbox is a string. You do understand that only one radio button placed directly on a form can be checked at a time. You need to place radio buttons in, for example a GroupBox, to have more than one checked on the form. Young people don't remember the push button radios.

Comment: `textBox5.Text = ( Basic, reg, pre, * textbox4.text )` doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by the first 3 arguments? What are you trying to multiply by.

Comment: I have three groups of radio buttons, that I am wanting to add, subtract and multiple by, each radiobutton value goes into a textbox but I need to calculate the sum and display the outcome:

Example: 
If two radio buttons are selected from different groups, I need to total there value together by * or - and then add to the sum total to the textbox,

Raidobutton1 = Basic = 10 (Textbox1)
RadioButon2 = Weekly = 4  (Textbox2)

10 * 4 = sumtotal --> Textbox3

Then add Textbox3 total with another textbox value, to get a grandtotal if that make sense?
Thankyou